# Is it possible to track user creation / removal in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, cdc

I've been tasked to create mechanism that would track adding users / removal in postgresql. (Deployed on EC2 in AWS)

At the begging I thought about triggers on pg_*authid table, eventually on pg*_user view, that would insert user info after creation to second table, and data from that table would be polled e.g. every 5 min, by a scheduled Lambda function resulting in near-real-time notifications, but there is no possibility to create trigger for system tables.

Second thought was to implement Kafka + Debezium connector to enable CDC on those system tables. By default Debezium connector tracks all non-system tables.

I've deployed connector including pg_*catalog schema and pg_auth_*id, with settings:

```
{
  "name": "postgres-cdc-demo",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "demo_db",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "name": "postgres-cdc-demo",
    "database.server.name": "DockerServer",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "table.include.list": "pg_catalog.pg_authid",
    "schema.include.list":"pg_catalog"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "postgres-cdc-demo",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

But it seems that it's not tracking changes for those tables.

Do you have any advices how it can be solved, or how can i make this connector work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution? I tried create the connector with pg_catalog schema but got permission denied even with root users.